# Polymer linking via json

Tags: json, anchor, polymer

Sorry this is such a basic newbie question; I can't find anything in the Polymer documents. Say I have a set of cards - like in the getting started tutorial - each with some info. Can I add a button supplying an anchor/link to more detail/ document/image/pdf... Is it possible to set those links into polymer via json?
Here is what I've tried:
Placing url links (tried absolute and relative) in json, like:(excerpt){

```
 "uid": 4,
    "text" : "Blah blah blah",
    "Legal" : "Case",
    "iconurl" : "../images/svgs/goto.svg",
    "url":"http://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/Admin/2013/314.html",
    "username" : "BBCS",
    "avatar" : "../images/svgs/complaint.svg",
    "favorite": false,
      "stage": "incident"
  },
  {
    "uid": 5,
    "text" : "Blah blah blah",
    "Legal" : "Contact Guidance",
    "iconurl" : "../images/svgs/goto.svg",
      "url":"../assets/docs/stuff.pdf",
    "username" : "SCSC",
    "avatar" : "../images/svgs/complaint.svg",
    "favorite": false,
      "stage": "incident"
  }
```

...and then, in post-list, imported paper-button and paper-icon-button, and used paper-icon-button to link to "iconurl", like so:

```
<paper-icon-button src="{{post.iconurl}}" onclick="_onclick()">Go</paper-icon-button>
```

This binding on src doesn't work. Nor does explicitly setting a custom icon on src:
e.g. src="../images/svgs/goto.svg" - but in both cases the text Go does appear as a paper button. If I place the icon source inside paper-icon-button css style as background-image then it does show up - repeatedly... as long as there is text also. No text; no image.

Then in script tag in post-list template I have placed an _onclick() function:

```
function _onclick(){
      document.getElementById("{{post.url}}");
    };
```

- with and without handlebars...

Here is the full code for post-list.html. ( I have taken the postcard tutorial and am playing about with it...).
The paper-icon-button now works in this scenario. The greyed out version didn't. And as for my javascript attempts to bind to json - all commented out here below - well, nothing works.

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../post-service/post-service.html">
<link rel="import" href="post-card.html">
 <link rel="import"
    href="../components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
     <link rel="import"
    href="../components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

<polymer-element name="post-list" attributes="show">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    post-card {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
        paper-icon-button{
         float:right;
            margin-left: 30px;
           margin-right: 20px;
            color: #0dddad;
            <!--background-image: url("../images/svgs/goto.svg");-->
        }
    </style>

    <post-service id="service" posts="{{posts}}">
    </post-service>

    <div layout vertical center>

      <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
        <post-card>
          <img src="{{post.avatar}}" width="70" height="70">
          <paper-icon-button
    raisedButton
    class="colored"
    iconSrc="../images/svgs/eyeyeY.svg"
    on-click="{{goLink}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <!--<paper-icon-button src="../images/svgs/eyeyeO.svg" onclick="_onclick()">o</paper-icon-button>-->
          <h2>{{post.username}}</h2>
          <p>{{post.text}}</p>
          <h4>{{post.Legal}}</h4>
        </post-card>
      </template>

    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
       Polymer({});
  //Polymer('post-list', {
    //goLink: function(e) {
         //window.getElementById=e.target.open({{api/post.url}});

     //return document.getElementById("post.url")
     //document.location.href =e.target("{{post.url}}");
   // };
         //});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Yes. (for a more detailed answer please supply a more detailed question, including what you tried and what exactly you struggle with)

Comment: More detail added.  In order to make ulr links and open new pages via json, should I be using core-ajax?

Comment: Binding to `src` should work. What's the rest of your code look like.

Comment: More detail added. Binding now works...